# I want to ask which preposition is suitable in this situation?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

you walk very fast. you're always five steps ..... me. 
I want to ask which preposition is suitable in this situation.

Comment: You are always five steps **ahead of** me.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities.

A couple of common ones:

> You're always five steps **ahead of** me.
>   You're always five steps **in front of** me.

A few less common ones:

> You're always five steps **in advance of** me.
>   You're always five steps **beyond** me.
>   You're always five steps **faster than** me.